# How can I use THROW combined with testing values in a TRY CATCH?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I coded this:

```
BEGIN TRY

SELECT @TestUserId = UserId,
       @TestCreatedBy = CreatedBy
FROM   UserTest
WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId

IF ( @TestUserId != @UserId & @TestCreatedBy != @UserID)
BEGIN
   THROW 50000,'THROW TEST',1
END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SET @RC = 1
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
   RETURN
END CATCH
```

I am having a problem with the line starting with IF. It gives an error saying:

```
! - Incorrect syntax
```

Also the THROW line shows an error

Can someone advise me how I can make this throw and error correctly and how I can catch it. Can I catch in a block specific to the 50000 code?

Comment: change `IF ( @TestUserId != @UserId & @TestCreatedBy != @UserID)` to `IF ( @TestUserId != @UserId AND @TestCreatedBy != @UserID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope `@UserId` is defined somewhere. The problem is with `&` - replace it with `AND`.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the AND.  Any ideas about why THROW is showing an error?

Comment: @SamanthaJ - It will show incorrect syntax near `Throw` and `END` but still it will work

Comment: I found the error is because I didn't have a ; before the throw

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
BEGIN TRY

SELECT @TestUserId = UserId,
       @TestCreatedBy = CreatedBy
FROM   UserTest
WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId

IF ( @TestUserId != @UserId AND @TestCreatedBy != @UserID)
BEGIN
   raiserror('THROW TEST',16,1)
END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SET @RC = 1
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
   RETURN
END CATCH
```